# Module moment not found after installing react-native-community/netinfo

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, yarnpkg

I am facing the issue "react-native-community/netinfo" while running my react-native project.

I have reinstall this module but get the same error again.
Before I run my application, I run Yarn and pod install, that run successfully, but after that it is showing this error that I have shown in the in this image. How can I resolve this error to run my project?

I am attaching the error and followed the given steps but it did not work for me.

> Unhandled JS Exception: @react-native-community/netinfo: NativeModule.RNCNetInfo is null. To fix this issue try these steps:
>
> - Run `react-native link @react-native-community/netinfo` in the project root.
> - Rebuild and re-run the app.
> - If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then rebuild and re-run the app. You may also need to re-open Xcode to get the new pods.
> - Check that the library was linked correctly when you used the link command by running through the manual installation instructions in the README.
> - If you are getting this error while unit testing you need to mock the native module. Follow the guide in the README

Comment: try to add moment from yarn add moment

Comment: I am also getting this error. When you refer to moment do you mean https://momentjs.com/? I am not using it...